# Knowing when to Add/Replace element to an array list

Tags: java, arraylist

So I have an array of customers.  Customers contain firstName, lastName and an array of cars.

```
String Firstname 
String Lastname 
Cars car[]
```

Cars contains

```
String Make
String Model
String Colour
```

The amount of cars can vary from customer to customer so one customer could have 2 cars and another could have 4.
In my scenario I have a list of customers which I am looping through and I want to create an array of their cars. But I want to do this in a specific way.  So say I have a 3 customers and 7 cars with the following data:

```
[Jim, Bob, [car1, car2]]
[John, Smith, [car3, car4, car5]]
[Jack, Jones, [car6, car7]]
```

The car data is:

```
Car1 – [Renault, Clio, Red]
Car2 – [Audi, A4, Green]
Car3 – [Seat, Leon, Yellow]
Car4 – [BMW, i8, Black]
Car5 – [Vauxhall, Astra, Silver]
Car6 – [Volkswagen, Golf, Grey]
Car7 – [Subaru, Impreza, Purple]
```

What I would like to do is firstly loop through the customers and then loop through the cars and add to an array carList.

```
ArrayList<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<Car>();

For (cust in customers)
{
    var i = 0;    
    For (car in cust.cars)
    {
        carsList.add(car)
        i++ 
    }   
}
```

But here is where I want to do something a little different.  On the first customer we have two cars, this will add those two cars to the carsList array.  The second customer has 3 cars, I want this customers cars to overwrite car1 and car2 from the first customer and then add car3.  On the final customer I want car6 and car7 to overwrite car3 and car4 from customer 2 but keep car 6.  The following shows what the output after each cycle:

loop1: [car1, car2]

loop2: [car3, car4, car5]

loop3 (final result): [car6, car7, car5]

I know I can use an int variable to track the position of the arrays (I included it in the code) and I know I can use arryList.set to overwrite data in a certain position.  My issue is however I don't want any index out of bounds exceptions to be thrown.  How can I tell when to use add to add to the array or set to overwrite an existing value?

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks for any help I may get

Comment: There is overloaded method to add object in `List`  `add(index, element)` you can use this to overwrite the old values.

Comment: make your declaration outside the for loop: ArrayList<Car> carsList;  initialize arraylist each time for your customer by doing carsList = new ArrayList<Car>(); inside the customerLoop but outside the car loop

Comment: This method wont overwrite an existing value, it simply adds the element at that location and moves the other element along.  Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an index but check if the size is lower that index, so you won't run in a IndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
ArrayList<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Customer cust : customers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cust.cars.length; i++) {
        if (carsList.size() > i) {
           carsList.set(i, cust.cars[i]);
        } else {
           carsList.add(cust.cars[i]);
        }
    }   
}
```